# "Isn't that..." expanding to "Is not that..."

Tags: word-order, questions, negation, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

My question is whether the use of "isn't" in sentences of the form "Isn't she lovely?" a rule, or an exception to a rule?

Because if you expand the contraction out, then you have "Is not she lovely?" which is obviously(?) wrong. You would say "Is she not lovely?" I think...?

Comment: The only rule you should keep in mind is not to use it in narrative or formal writing, since contractions and other informal aspects of speech/dialogue are usually improper grammar.

Answer (score 1):

"isn't" is not really expressed over a fact, so it does not really implicate the word meaning as "is not". Isn't that weird?, or Isn't she lovely? is asked when you know that it is and you want to 'confirm' the same 'feelings' with others.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the meaning and usage, but wanted to know about the grammar, or if it is just idiomatic usage.